# How can I expand the UINavigationBar to cover the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't want the status bar to disappear. I simply want the navigation bar to be 64px high instead of 44. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have used for adding blur view to both Status Bar and Navigation bar, I have given `CGRect frame= CGRectMake(0, -20, 1000, 64);` so as Blur View on Navigation Bar covers status bar too. For that I have given **Y Co-Ordinate** as **-20**. You can replace this Blur View with any *uiview* you want and thus cover your status bar with Navigation Bar. Also, I have given height of Navigation Bar as **64** as per your requirement.

```
CGRect bounds = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];
CGRect frame= CGRectMake(0, -20, 1000, 65);
visualEffectView.frame = frame;
visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:visualEffectView];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:visualEffectView];
```